# Good practices for menu heavy games (in Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game (in Unity3D) which consists of a dozen menus and no real 2d/3d game world. From a programmer's perspective it is just a bunch of buttons, labels and images.

To not have everything inside of one big menu class, I decided to split the code in parts for every menu. The result is that I've got a dozen classes which themselves have all the references to their gameobjects and e.g. the button methods.

My problem is that almost everything in my project is static by now, because these menus do not get instantiated multiple times and I have to access variables and methods from one menu with the script of another menu.

Thus my question is what the best practice would be for this situation. I've got a couple of ideas, how I could do it, but unfortunately I didn't get to learn what to do in such a situation.

So if you straight up want to suggest something, feel free to do so. :)

My ideas:

1) Make a controller which has static instances of all menus. A button-method in class 'A' could then call `Controller.B.x`. This does work, but I dislike putting "Controller" everywhere so often, because most classes access methods and variables from other classes so often, that it's just ugly.

2) Make these menus all be singletons. Afaik are singletons "ok" for something like this, but aren't they just shifting the static instance to their own class instead of one controller? When I switched from option 1) to this with one class, basically `Controller.A.x` became `A.instance.x`, where "instance" is the static instance of the class inside the class.

3) Keeping everything the way it is, having variables and method being static whenever I need to access them statically from another class, otherwise make them private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The game is probably not a *"bunch of buttons, labels and images"*.**

I suggest to forget about the menus for a second, **focus on the model of your game**, create classes strictly for that. You don't put things like *"how much of a currency does the player have"* in any menu, it should exist in a `Player` class or similar (the model).

Once you can manipulate your model from a single test controller class, and simply log the results in debug console, you're ready to do the same with menus.

After that, you can much easily create user interfaces to read /display (creating labels and images on the fly) and write (hook button events into) the model beneath. These UI classes will probably have so much in common after that.

You can use [**`UnityEvent`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) class for communication between UI and model, they are nicely shown in the Inspector (the same events used in [UI Events and Event Triggers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers)).

Fore more general info, Google on some design patterns like [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), or [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/).

Comment: Ok, now I have a player class with all data relevant to the player in it. I also have a controller with references of all menus and the player. Now a button in a menu is supposed to change the amount of e.g. gold that the player has. The method called by the button is in the corresponding menu class. What should the method do now in principal? My current implementation would be like Controller.player.gold+=x;

Comment: @Tavados Each menu (view) should have it's own controller. From those view controllers you can manipulate the model just you did. But you'll need backward communication as well, so model should have some delegate hooks, where the controllers can "subscribe" to keep the UI updated on each model change automatically.

Comment: @Tavados Do you need all menus all the time? Why don't just present one at a time?

Comment: Because the menus are modular. One menu can be an overlay or popup in another one. I'll just accept your answer now, but I think that all of this is building up so much overhead and inconvenience, that I surely don't know if I like it better than what I had for a project on which I am the only programmer. It does however make a lot of sense to do it like this, if its a team project.

Comment: I think it is more about flexibility. What will happen when you implemented a lot of stuff, and you want to change something.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to strongly consider why you have statics. I understand your reasoning that they are singletons but I don't think that is a good enough reason.

I hope you are using the Unity GUI features properly.

I would just write a base "Menu" component. Then you can add references into the sub classes. For example.

You have a "StartMenu" class derived from "Menu" which is derived from "MonoBehavior". In "StartMenu" you write a method "ShowCharacterCreationMenu()". Then add a button component and hook the method up to that button press. StartMenu will have to have a reference to Character menu. This is the classical OOP approach.

I would do this a little differently though. Unity's strength lies in component based design so I would lean towards that. I would probably create a "Transition" component class that listens for a button press. When that button is pressed it goes to the next menu.

Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, but I think it is not really applicable to my case. Inheritance doesn't make sense imo, because there is nothing that these menus have in common. The static variables I have are for example "which menu is currently opened" and "how much of a currency does the player have". These values should exist just once in the code, but whereever I put them, I have to access them from a lot of other menus. I think it wouldn't even help to have a Player-class here, because I'd need an instance of that which is again not so nice to access compared to just Player.currency.

Comment: I thought you were using static methods but static variables is something I would avoid. I strongly recommend that if an object needs a reference to another menu, you should give it that menu. I went down the static variable path once when building menus and regretted it a lot.

Comment: But that would result mostly in n menus each having n-1 references to the other menus. I don't see that this is any better or even faster than static usages, is it?

Comment: It is certainly safer because menus can't access things they shouldn't. The use of global variables is usually a symptom of a larger problem or laziness. 

How about having a class that holds references to each menu, then each menu can reference it. That way you can make it seem global without it being global. Have a look at the mediator design pattern. I use it a lot for this sort of thing